# ,"error":"Not authorized" when attempting to get tweet from user with hashtag

Tags: api, twitter, hashtag

I am attempting to get all tweets fro a specific user with a hashtag. The url I am using is:

https://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.json?q=%23jdmr%2Bfrom%3ABarrySpang

which without the URL encoding is simply: https://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.json?q=#jdmr+from:BarrySpang

When I try it in twitter search (as stated in the API docs) and it displays the desired results, however when I try the above URL I get a 401 response with this error message: {"request":"/1/statuses/user_timeline.json?q=%23jdmr%2Bfrom%3ABarrySpang","error":"Not authorized"}

Please can you advise me on this

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`statuses/user_timeline` doesn't have `q` parameter

You should be using `search`: https://api.twitter.com/1/search.json?q=%23jdmr%2Bfrom%3ABarrySpang

Answer (score 1):

I just received the same error when running python-twitter's `GetFollowers()` method on a user account that had been suspended. If others receive the same error, it might pay to check whether the account you're trying to access still exists.